# Infinite non deviating slope

Tags: systems-of-equations, infinity

Okay, I had a question that my math teacher didn't know the answer to, and that I haven't found an answer for on the web. Say you are graphing a system of equations, right, and you have (hypothetically) two slopes of 2, and 2 and one infinitieth, both starting at the origin. Since it would take an infinitely long time for the two lines to deviate, could they be said to coincide? I understand they're different numbers, but if you can never reach the end of infinity, therefore never deviating from the other line, wouldn't they be the same? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "one infinitieth." As the difference between the slopes goes to zero, the lines will coincide.

Comment: Can you give two example functions? Exaclty what is meant by "one infinitieth" is important

Comment: 1/infinity. Also written as 0.01 with the 0 in the tenths place being non-terminating.

Answer (score 1):

In the standard reals,
infinitesimals
do not exist.
What corresponds to this idea
is $\lim_{c \to 0} f(c)$
for some function $f$.

In your case,
consider
the lines
$y=2x$
and
$y=(2+c)x$
and let $c \to 0$.

For any particular $c$,
the two lines differ
at $x$ by
$cx$.
You can therefore say two things:

1. For any fixed value of $c$,
   the two line get arbitrarily far apart
   for large $x$.
2. For any fixed value of $x$,
   the two lines
   can be made arbitrarily close
   at $x$
   by choosing $c$
   small enough.

As to what happens
when both $x$ gets large
and $c$ gets small,
it depends on how
that happens.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Sorry to be buggy bu could you help explain that in laymans terms? I only got half of that...